# AttributeError: 'tuple" object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to retrieve specific cell values from an excel sheet, and here is my code.

```
import openpyxl
file=openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/epeeham/Desktop/xsdi-auto/Test-XSDI.xlsx')
sheet=file.get_sheet_by_name('ExportList')
row_count=sheet.max_row;
for x in range(2, row_count):
  title=sheet['Ax'].value
  ed=sheet['Bx'].value
  if "P" in ed:
     edi=ed[1:]
     edi1, edi2, edi3=edi.partition('-')
     edition=edi1
  else:
     edi1, edi2, edi3=ed.partition('-')
     edition=edi1
  n=sheet['Fx'].value
  number=n[:15]
  print(title + "   "   + edition + "     " +  number)
```

I get the following error.
AttributeError: 'tuple" object has no attribute 'value'. I dont know much about the loops in python. In C, we can something like for(i=2;i<=row_count;i++).  I dont know if my loop is current in the code. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You try to access an attribute `value` several times, post the full stack trace.

Comment: Without the xlsx file or the sheet, this code is not "reproducible".  The error means that, at one of these points, the value you are accessing (for example, maybe, `sheet['fx']` is returning a tuple (a series of immutable values).  You are then trying to access a property called "value", which is not a valid operand/property for a tuple.

Comment: if it is a tuple, you would access its elements with a slice notation using a numerical index.  So if `sheet['fx']` returned (45,50,123,6), the second element (50) would be accessed like so:  `sheet['fx'][1]`

Comment: We need to know the contents (or at least the layout) of the sheet.

Comment: Are there sheets called "Ax", "Bx", etc... or were you intending to substitute x's value into the string lookup?

Comment: Yes. Thats the thing i had done. I wanted to substitute x, but i used that in the same way i use in C. Afaq solution solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be with `sheet['Ax']` that you are doing. You won't be able to use `x` this way.

Try modifying your indexes like following in the code.

`title=sheet['A' + str(x)].value`

Answer (score 2):

I had a different problem that caused this error. My code was attempting to get the value of a cell in row zero (I ran the loop one row too far).

Row zero doesn't exist (sheets begin at row 1), hence the `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'` error.

Answer (score 0):

General structure : ws['A1'] = 'Stackoverflow'

NOTE : Try to print the cell name to check weather you are passing column name as 'A1', 'A3' like this or only 'A'.

Read this Becautiful Documentaion : https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Answer (score -1):

The above solution did not work in my case. I ended up using the following:

```
title=sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value
```